# Android Retrofit parsing

Tags: android, retrofit

i just followed exapmple :
https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/recyclerview-json-parsing.html
its working great ..i want to parse

```
[  
 {
  "song_name": "Hero",
  "song_id": "1990",
  "artist_name": "Enrique"
 },{
  "song_name": "African Queen",
  "song_id": "2004",
  "artist_name": "Tuface"
 }, {
  "song_name": "Ifunanyi",
  "song_id": "2012",
  "artist_name": "PSquare"
  }
]
```

Here is my code am getting blank..Am new to android
Give some ideas nothing else i want..Any one please guide me

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<ItemObject> data;
private MyAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}
private void initViews(){
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadJSON();
}
private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://toscanyacademy.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
            adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

My Request interface:

```
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("blog/mp.php")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

Json Response:

```
public class JSONResponse {
    private ItemObject[] obj;

    public ItemObject[] getAndroid() {
        return obj;
    }
}

public class ItemObject {

    public String getSong_name() {
        return song_name;
    }

    public String getSong_id() {
        return song_id;
    }

    public String getArtist_name() {
        return artist_name;
    }

    private String song_name,song_id,artist_name;
}
```

Here is my Adapter:

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<ItemObject> users;
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<ItemObject> first) {
    this.users = first;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.song_title.setText(users.get(i).getsong_name());
    viewHolder.song_id.setText(users.get(i).getsong_id());
    viewHolder.song_author.setText(users.get(i).getartist_name());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView song_title, song_id, song_author;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        song_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        song_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_id);
        song_author=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }
}
```

}

Row Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textColor="#000"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#000" />
```

Comment: Show your complete code.

Comment: Hi, i just updated my code..

Comment: your json is an array, not an object. You don't need `JSONResponse`, you can declare you interface directly as `Call<ArrayList<ItemObject>> getJSON();`

Comment: Thanks..can u please ellobrate...am new to retrofit and android feels bit difficult

Comment: Please add your layout code and MyAdapter class code.

Comment: Check what status code are you getting in onResponse.

Comment: Not entering into debug mode...It show blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your POJO class:
Example.java

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("song_name")
    @Expose
    private String songName;

    @SerializedName("song_id")
    @Expose
    private String songId;

    @SerializedName("artist_name")
    @Expose
    private String artistName;

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public String getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }

    public void setSongId(String songId) {
        this.songId = songId;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }
}
```

In your interface:

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("blog/mp.php")
    Call<List<Example>> getJSON();
}
```

And in your activity:

```
ArrayList<Example> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


//Inside loadJSON()

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://toscanyacademy.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    Call<List<Example>> listCall = request.getJSON();

                listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                            Example example = new Example();
                            example.setArtistName(response.body().get(i).getArtistName());
                            example.setSongId(response.body().get(i).getSongId());
                            example.setSongName(response.body().get(i).getSongName());
                            arrayList.add(example);
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Getting error  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Where have you written `ArrayList<Example> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
` ??

Comment: Thanks its working...I made mistake while copying..Thank u..i was struggling for 3 days..

Answer (score 1):

**Retrofit** saves you the trouble of parsing the `json` response.
Inorder to parse the `json` response, the **Modal class** should be **named** accordingly.

You can see in the example you followed, that the modal class `variables` are named after the`jsonObjects` in the response.

In your case,
the variables should be **song_name**, **song_id**, **artist_name**.

Try changing the modal class according to you response.

Hope this helps..! Happy coding :)

Comment: Debug and confirm that, you are getting the response in `onResponse` not on `onFailure` and also the response object contains the desired `jsonArray` @silentguy

Answer (score 0):

.baseUrl("http://toscanyacademy.com")
Try with .baseUrl("http://toscanyacademy.com**/**")

becasue when retrofit builds url it is like this in your situation 
http://toscanyacademy.comblog/mp.php

Comment: No changes..Still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to change as below if it helps:

```
private void initViews(){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

loadJSON();
}

RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
Call<List<ItemObject>> call = request.getJSON();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ItemObject>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ItemObject>> call, Response<List<ItemObject>> response) {
        for(ItemObject obj: response.body()) {
                data.add(obj);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ItemObject>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
    }
});
```